# Регулярное выражение для замены по условию

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста. Какое регулярное выражение поможет мне заменить каждый 1й символ в строке если это не "-" на "+".
Строка может иметь вид либо 
1. `00000000000`
либо 
2.`-0000034544`
Спасибо.

Comment: Что значит каждый первый символ. т.е. все символы кроме +- ? `/[^-]/`

Comment: Да, предполагается, что там скорее всего будет "0".

Comment: Тогда не называйте его _каждым_ потому как в строке только один 1й символ. А каждый первый - это все символы. Один заменили, следующий за ним опять первый

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так и сделать, как сказано. Просто меняем первый символ на `+`, если он не `-` (до кучи и не `+`):

```
$string =~ s/^[^-+]/\+/;
```